# Issue in extracting data from Complex data type of SQL via Java

Tags: java, jdbc, struct

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure from java, whose return type is a complex one.
Posting the code snippet below:

```
 //ProcResult is the Map containing the Procedure result
        java.sql.Struct jdbcStruct = (java.sql.Struct) (ProcResult.get(seq.intValue()));
        Object[] resultStructArray = null;
        resultStructArray = jdbcStruct.getAttributes();

    String serv =(String) resultStructArray[1];
    System.out.println(serv);
```

The procedure queries a table and fetches a `varchar2` value and the result is available in  `resultStructArray[1];`

**Expected output** : `Adsl_fixed`

**Actual output** : `0x4164736C5F6669786564`

Can someone help? What am I missing here?